Aggregates and Psuedorandomness
Psuedorandomness in compsci usually takes the form of Math.random — in binary it is theoretically possible to get a random-looking number from the method:
Math.random(MaxInteger) is expected to return a random-looking number on [0, 2^32)
Do you ever wonder if every number on [0, 2^32) is present in the resulting psuedorandom output? Perhaps a number like “5” appears more than once, and “2555” doesn’t appear at all…
I believe there is technically a solution for this issue using some form of “bit-shuffling”:
int x = 0xFEDCBA98
int y = SHUFFLING_MASK
x ^ y
For all non-negative integers, x^y would just rearrange the integers (all unique numbers produce unique outputs: one-to-one)
Regardless, I wanted to get into the topic of Aggregates:
Is it possible to rearrange a continuum of integers, so that a sample of the rearranged random numbers would always average to the same average as the theoretical average? (Yes, defeating the purpose of randomness— adding more predictability, but I’m just curious if anyone has heard of this problem, and has some insight)
Specifically,
If you were to select any N numbers from [0,2^32), after they were rearranged into a psuedorandom ordering, then the average of the N numbers is T — for all N-sized subsequences on [0, 2^32).
Does there exist ANY psuedorandom ordering, where this condition is true? (I think it’s impossible)
For example:
… 4, 3, 1, 2, 5 …
N = 2,
Ave(4,3)=(7/2)
Ave(2,5)=(7/2)
Ave(3,1)=2 != (7/2)
…
If N=3 then Ave(a,b,c)
If N=4 then Ave(a,b,c,d)
Etc.
Thank you for reading!
I’m curious what you all think about this topic

What is a "continuum of integers"?

If $0<N<2^{32}$ then there exist subsets of size $N$ with different averages, for example the subset of the least $N$ numbers has a strictly smaller average than the subset of the largest $N$ numbers.

I agree:
1,2,3 will certainly have a smaller average than 4,5,6. I’m also curious about rearranging the elements— so if the order was changed to [1,6,2,5,3,4] then 1,6 and 2,5 and 3,4 have the same averages (N=2) but 6,2 and 5,3 are possible pairs, and have different averages. I’m 90% sure that there is no solution though

You did not state in the question that the selection was supposed to contain consecutive members of the array. But even then it's impossible, because if you shift your selection 1 position to the right the average will decrease or increase depending on whether the new member to the right is greater or less than the number that fell off on the left.

Ah, sorry for the late reply, but that is a really good visualization. Thank you for your feedback! That makes a lot of sense now
